# How can I configure SOLR to find a multi-word date string in text?

Tags: solr, dovecot

For example, I am using dovecot-solr and need to configure SOLR to be able to pick up a Subject that is:

```
Your interview on November 23, 2023 and the corresponding link
```

If I search for "November 23, 2023" or "November 13", it does not show, but if I search for "November" it does. What settings should I use with SOLR to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the Analysis page under Solr's admin and enter the indexed text and what your query is, and you'll see exactly how the content gets split into tokens and then used for searching.